# How to change TextField underline border color when it is desabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change TextFiled underline color when it is disabled

```
child: TextField(
    ***enabled: false,***
    controller: resultController,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder:  UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
        labelText: resultLableText,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Look at the below code, it will easily solve your problem:

---

```
TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Your hint here",
              //defalult border
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.green)),
              //disabled border
              disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
              //enabled border
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.blue)),
              //error boreder
              errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.red)),
              //focused border
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.purple)),
              //error while focused border
              focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.amber)),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure that there is a method you can use to check if a `TextField` is disabled, but a way you can do it is you can create a `bool` that keeps track if the `TextField` is disabled.

1. Create the bool

```dart
bool isDisabled = false;
```

2. Make a function that changes the value

```dart
Function<void> changeDisabled() {
setState() {
    isDisabled ? isDisabled = false : isDisabled = true
}
}
```

3. Check the status of `isDisabled` in your code.

```dart
child: TextField(
    enabled: false,
    controller: resultController,
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.orange, fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder:  UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: isDisabled ? Colors.white : Colors.black)),
        labelText: resultLableText,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the underline color of the TextField if its disabled in the same way you did for when its enabled by using the `disabledBorder` property of the `InputDecoration` like :

```
 InputDecoration(
        enabledBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
        labelText: resultLableText,
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        disabledBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
      ),
```

or specifying it in the ThemeData like :

```
 MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
        disabledBorder:
            UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)),
      )),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```